# How to use Chuck in Retrofit2

Tags: android, android-studio, okhttp

I want to add ChuckInterceptor to okHttpClient. There is a problem with context. How can I set MainActivity context to chuck?

```
public Parser(){
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(new ChuckInterceptor(context))
                .build();

        mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
    }
```

And here is how I am calling Parser

```
Parser.getInstance().getInfo().getUpdate(check).enqueue(new Callback<MobileCheck>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MobileCheck> call, retrofit2.Response<MobileCheck> response) {
                mobileCheck = response.body();
                mainPresenter.enterApplication(false, true,
                        mobileCheck.getResult().getUpdate(), mobileCheck.getResult().getUpgrade());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MobileCheck> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

> first, create Singleton Instance of the app

```
  public class App extends Application {
    // Create the instance
    private static App instance;

    public static App getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (App.class) {
                if (instance == null)
                    instance = new App();
            }
        }
        // Return the instance
        return instance;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

}
```

> second register in applicaiton in manifest

```
<application
        android:name=".App"
 ....
>
```

then you can use application content in chuck

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().
       addInterceptor(new ChuckInterceptor(App.getInstance().getApplicationContext()))
       .build();
```